# Dockerizing SpringBoot application with MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, docker

My spring boot application is working fine when running it locally. But when I put that on docker it throws error saying that mysql connection cannot be made

Error in the console

```
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   ... 24 common frames omitted
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  | Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |   ... 39 common frames omitted
srikulamedura-skm-server-1  |
srikulamedura-skm-server-1 exited with code 1
```

This is Dockerfile code for spring boot application

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  skm-server:
    build:
      context: sri-kula-medura-server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - skm
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://skmdb:3307/skm_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true 
    depends_on:
      - skmdb

  skmdb:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - skm
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'skm_db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'skm_user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    expose:
      - '3307'
    volumes:
      - skm-db:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  skm:
volumes:
  skm-db:
```

And this is my application properties codes

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/skm_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=skm_user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

SQL Connection successfuly made

[image]

MySQL connection successfully established and exposed the port 3307. But spring application is not making the connection with mysql. Can someone suggest me how to connect mysql with spring boot inside docker

Comment: Does spring auto-bind its properties to similar environment variables? I.e. gets `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` actually get mapped to `spring.datasource.url`?

Comment: You're connecting to port 3307, but MySQL uses port 3306.  Connections between containers don't use (or require) `ports:`.

Comment: @Turing85 no it is not auto binding. That was the mistake I have done. I have to call that environment variable inside the application.properties.

Thank you for your comment

Comment: @DavidMaze yeah. I was defining env variable containing the JDBC URL. By using that in the application.properties the error was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your question you are defining environment variable named "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL" in docker compose.

You can try changing this line in application.propereties file :
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/skm_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

to :
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}

Accept this answer if this helps and upvote it because I want to earn reputations to comment on one question and get help from the user who have asked that question.

Let me know if some other error occurs

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. But I also had to change the spring.datasource.url port to 3306 since it is the port mysql running inside the container

Answer (score 0):

Because I am setting up the JDBC URL in a environment variable I had to change application.properties as this

spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}

And also I needed to change the port in JDBC url from 3307 to 3306
( jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skm_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true )